# lualatex not available in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, latex

I want to use `lualatex`for compiling Latex document based on Luatex. I have installed those packages: *luatex, texlive-binaries, texlive-luatex* …but no `lualatex`binary can be found. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`texlive-latex-base`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/texlive-latex-base/filelist). Note that for answering questions like this, the "search the contents of packages" at the bottom of https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages can be quite helpful, in addition to local tools like `apt-file`

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a command line alternative for the "search the contents…" ? Something like `apt-cache search` or does `apt-file`does this job?

Comment: @smartmic `apt-file search /usr/bin/lualatex` should do it. At least once you've run `apt-file update` to download the lists.